# Visual studio 2015 installed on win 7

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed VS 2015  for a week. I can't create a App  Blank project. In MainPage.xaml VS 2015 want to instal win 10.
My PC is win 7 PK1.
What is wrong? Please help me
[the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/preyc.png)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64ef706d-601d-4f6d-8abc-83b2f5306421/uwpvisual-studio-requires-newer-version-of-windows-to-display-the-content-please-update-windows?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of the project type you're using (targetting UWP): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn975273.aspx

> **Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 support**
>
> If you choose to develop Universal Windows apps with Visual Studio 2015 on a platform other than Windows 10, these are the restrictions:
>
> - Windows 8.1: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can use the emulators in Visual Studio, but not the simulator.
> - Windows 7: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can’t use the emulators or the simulator in Visual Studio either.
>
> You can only use the XAML designer if your development platform is Windows 10.

Comment: Is there some decision for win 7 and this app

Comment: @RumianaDimova what do you mean? You can create either 'WPF app' or 'Forms app' if you want Windows 7 support. Universal apps are Windows 10 (8.1 possibly?)+ only.